# What is the meaning of ++arp[c];

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

What is the difference between

```
int *arp = NULL;
int c;
++arp[c];
```

And

```
int *arp = NULL;
int c;
arp[c]; c++;
```

Please I need to know the meaning of this increment `++arp[c];`

Comment: `c` is uninitialized, so has an indeterminate value. Using it as an index on an array has undefined behavior.

Comment: arp is NULL and c has an unknown initial value. So it's undefined. But if that wasn't the case, then it would increase the value of whatever was inside arp at index c.

Comment: What does the statement `arp[c];` do? This code is meaningless.

Comment: There is no difference: they are both undefined behaviour. But if you are asking the difference between `++arp[c];` and `arp[c]; c++;` or `arp[c++];` the first increments the array element and the second increments the array index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```c
++arp[c];
```

This dereferences `arp[c]` (same as `*(arp + c)`) and then uses the pre-increment operator to increase the value in `arp[c]` by 1. `c` remains unchanged.

```c
arp[c];
c++;
```

This dereferences `arp[c]` but doesn't do anything with it so it's pointless. After that it uses the post-increment operator to increase `c` by 1. `arp[c]` remains unchanged.

Note: Both snippets have undefined behavior because `arp` points at `NULL` and `c` is unintialized when you read from it.

Comment: Thank you Ted! please can you give example about  ++arp[c];

Comment: @george You're welcome. Here's an [example](https://godbolt.org/z/54G9EEY8q)